# Windows batch script spawn normal windows copy process

Tags: file, batch-file, copy, bandwidth

Im writing a batch script to help me collect some bandwidth data about numerous offices on our WAN. It uses random data file creator to help me avoid wan optimisers affecting the results.

How can I copy a file by spawning a standard windows copy window that shows transfer rate?

If i use the 'copy' method, it just copies silently in the cmd window and i cant see the rate.

```
if not exist "C:\temp\xfertest" mkdir C:\test\xfertest
rdfc C:\test\xfertest\random100.dat 100000000
copy C:\test\xfertest\random100.dat \\nat-srv-007\Deliver
exit
```

Comment: The `copy` command has no way to display the rate of transfer.

Comment: That *standard Windows copy window* is the result of the Windows API `SHFileOperation` function. It can't be invoked from a batch file, and there is no means of displaying bandwidth from a file copy operation in batch. If you want to do so, you're going to need to write a real app to do it.

Comment: Thanks Ken. I suspected as much. Just trying to save myself from writing an app just for a one off job.

Comment: Robocopy shows percentages and time but if you know the size of the file and you get a time stamp at the beginning and end of the copy you can figure out the transfer rate.

Comment: PsPing have bandwidth testing ability (-b), try to script it instead to use widows copy.

Answer (score 1):

This vbscript wrappped in a batch file will do what you want. Save it with a `.bat/.cmd` extension. Or without the first line with a `.vbs` extension.

The technic used is based on com and works with  every script language supporting it.
Just to see start/end date time, total bytes and bytes per/s it outputs these values to the console after the copy dialog window has vanished.

```
rem^ &@cscript //nologo //e:vbscript "%~f0" %* & exit /b
' Copy with the windows dialog box 
Option Explicit
Dim cArgs   : Set cArgs = WScript.Arguments
Dim iArgCnt : iArgCnt = cArgs.Count
Dim sSource : sSource = cArgs.Item(0)
Dim sDest   : sDest   = cArgs.Item(1)
Dim oFS     : Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim oSH     : Set oSH = CreateObject("shell.application")
Dim oFile, Size, dStart, dEnd

If iArgCnt <> 2 Then 
    Wscript.Echo "Wrong args, need SourceFile and DestFolder"
    Wscript.Quit
End if

If oFS.FileExists(sSource) Then 
    Set oFile = oFS.GetFile(sSource)
    Size = oFile.Size 
    If oFS.FolderExists(sDest) Then 
        dStart = Now()
        Wscript.Echo "Copy : " & sSource & "  " & sDest
        Wscript.Echo "Start: " & dStart  & "   Size : " & Size
        FolderCopyHere sSource, sDest
        dEnd = Now()
        Wscript.Echo "End  : " & dEnd    & "   per/s: " & _
          Int(Size / DateDiff("s", dStart, dEnd))
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "Destination Folder doesn't exist" & sDest
    End if
Else
    Wscript.Echo "Source file doesn't exist" & sSource
End if
Wscript.Quit

function FolderCopyHere(sSource,sDest)
    dim oFld
    set oFld = oSH.NameSpace(sDest)
    if not oFld is nothing then
        oFld.CopyHere(sSource)
    end if
    set oFld = nothing
end function
```

Returning this output on my pc

```
20:28:24 C:\Test________________________________________
> k:\Bat\CopyExpl.cmd c:\test\big.file Q:\Test

20:28:36 C:\Test________________________________________
> rem  &
Copy : c:\test\big.file  Q:\Test
Start: 2016-10-30 20:28:36   Size : 2147483648
End  : 2016-10-30 20:29:10   per/s: 63161283

20:29:10 C:\Test________________________________________
```

The Rem stems from the wrapper the dialog box is widely known. HTH